# SQL script returning FAILED: SemanticException in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

My query is below:

```
SELECT Round (sum(column1),2) AS alias, column 2, column3 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table 2
ON table1.column3 = table2.acolumn3
Group by column3
```

Hive keeps returning the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Column column3 Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

I have read several threads related to this error message. Theses scripts are usually quite complex. Mine is very simple. Cannot understand why Hive is throwing this message on such a simplistic script.

Comment: use a proper table alias for `column3` in `select`, because it is present in both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Round (sum(column1),2) AS alias, tab1.column2 as col2, tab2.column3 as col3
FROM table1 tab1
INNER JOIN table2 tab2
ON tab1.column3 = tab2.acolumn3
Group by tab2.column3
```